# Get property from the decoded JSON Web Token payload in Typescript

Tags: typescript, jwt

I have the following code in Typescript:

[Code snipper (Pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/AuN2pNnh)

So, the problem is that the `jwt.verify()` function returns a `JwtPayload` or `string`. I exactly know the shape of the expected payload (which is an `object`):

`{id: number, email: string, role: string}`

When I got the decoded payload:

`const decoded = jwt.verify(accessToken, Env.jwtPrivateKey);`

I was unable to access `decoded.role` property. The compiler complained:

> Property 'role' does not exist on type 'string | JwtPayload'

So I solved the issue with the implementation linked above. In nutshell I used an `assertion function` to do check the type of `decoded` and the existence of `role` property. I marked `decoded` as `unknown`. **Is it necessary?** With this approach the code works fine.

My questions are: **Is it a good practice to handle this way this issue? Is there better, simpler or more elegant solution?**